# C++ Program, output issue

Tags: c++

This is a program I had to write for my c++ class, there are no issues with it except that my output only shows 1 decimal place and I need it to show two (ex: 2.22, not 2.2). Do any of you have an idea has to how I could format this to make that change?

```
// Author:    
// Assignment: 7

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> // I/O
#include <iomanip> // For setw()
using namespace std;

ofstream     outputfile("output.txt");     // Output file

const int    MAX_FILE_NAME = 35;            // Max space allocated for file name
const double INTEREST_RATE1 = 0.015;
const double INTEREST_RATE2 = 0.010;
const double LEVEL_ONE_BALANCE = 1000.00;
const double MINIMUM_PAYMENT = 10.00;
const double MINIMUM_PAYMENT_PERCENT = 0.10;

class Account
{
public:
Account( double Balance, double InterestRate1, double InterestRate2);
Account( );
double Payment();
double InterestDue();
double TotalAmountDue();
void output(ostream &out); // Print values on output stream out();

private:
double balance;
double interest;
double payment;
double interest_rate1;
double interest_rate2;
double total_amount_due;
};

// Utility Functions
void open_input(ifstream& input, char name[]); // Get file name & Open file
void process_file(ifstream& input);            // Read each value & process it

int main() 
// Parameters: None
// Returns:    Zero
// Calls:      open_input(), process_file()    
{  char again;             // Does user want to go through loop again?
   char file_name[MAX_FILE_NAME + 1]; // Name of file to be processed
   ifstream input_numbers;            // For working with input file

   cout << "This program computes the interest due, total amount due,\n"
        << "and the minimum payment for a revolving credit account.\n" << endl;
   system("pause"); // Hold message on screen until key is pressed

   do 
   {  
      system("cls");                           // Clear screen
      open_input(input_numbers, file_name);    // Get file name & open file
      process_file(input_numbers);             // Process values in file
      input_numbers.close();                   // Close file

      cout << "\nDo you want to process another file (Y/N)? ";
      cin >> again;
      cin.ignore(256, '\n');  // Remove Enter key from keyboard buffer

   } while ( again == 'y' || again == 'Y'); 

   cout << "\nEnd of Program!" << endl;
   outputfile << "\n\nThanks for using CreditCalculator!\f"; 
   outputfile.close();

   return 0; 
}  // End of main()



void open_input(ifstream& input, char name[]) //Open file, exit on error
// Parameters: Variables for input file reference nad input file name
    // Returns:    None
// Calls:      None
{  int count = 0;             // Count number of tries
   do // Continue until we get a valid file name and can open file
   {  count++;
      if (count != 1)  // Issue error message if we are trying again.
      {  cout << "\n\aInvalid file name or file does not exist. Please try again." 
              << endl;
      }
      cout << "\nEnter the input file name (maximum of " << MAX_FILE_NAME
           << " characters please)\n:> ";
      cin.get(name, MAX_FILE_NAME + 1);// Gets at most MAX_FILE_NAME characters
      cin.ignore(256, '\n');           // Remove Enter key from keyboard buffer
      input.clear();                   // Clear all error flags, if any, from prev try
      input.open(name,ios_base::in); // Open only if file exists
   } while (input.fail() );            // If can't open file, try again
} // End of open_input()

void process_file(ifstream& input) 
{  double value;              
   Account thisAccount;             
   while (input >> value)     
   {
      thisAccount = Account(value, INTEREST_RATE1, INTEREST_RATE2);
      thisAccount.output(cout); 
      thisAccount.output(outputfile);   
   }
} 

// Account Class

Account::Account(double Balance, double InterestRate1, double InterestRate2):balance(Balance),interest_rate1(InterestRate1),interest_rate2(InterestRate2),interest(0.00),payment(0.00),total_amount_due(0.00)

    {
balance = Balance;
interest_rate1 = InterestRate1;
interest_rate2 = InterestRate2;
Payment();
total_amount_due = balance + interest;
    }

Account::Account()
{
    balance = 0.00;
}
double Account::InterestDue()
{ 
    return interest;
}
double Account::TotalAmountDue()
{
    return total_amount_due;
}
void Account::output(ostream &out) // Print values on output stream out();
{
   out << "\n\nBalance   : $" << setw(8) << balance << endl;
   out <<     "Payment   : $" << setw(8) << payment << endl;
   out <<     "Interest  : $" << setw(8) << interest << endl;
   out <<     "Total due : $" << setw(8) << total_amount_due << endl;

}
double Account::Payment()
{

double newbalance = 0.00;

if ( balance > LEVEL_ONE_BALANCE)
     interest = (balance - LEVEL_ONE_BALANCE) * interest_rate2 + LEVEL_ONE_BALANCE *  interest_rate1;
else
     interest = balance * interest_rate1;
newbalance = balance + interest;

payment = newbalance * MINIMUM_PAYMENT_PERCENT;

if (newbalance < MINIMUM_PAYMENT_PERCENT)
     payment=newbalance; 
else
     if ( payment < MINIMUM_PAYMENT)
          payment=MINIMUM_PAYMENT;

return payment;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use **[setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/)** to set the decimal precision value of your choice.

Comment: as in  cout << "payment :$" << setprecision(2) << payment << endl; ?

Comment: @WilliamLovejoy:Yes. Did you check the doccumentation of the api link that was mentioned in the answer? It pretty much explains everything clearly.Read it, Understand it and then use it and it will serve you much better in future.